# Symfony upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3 Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath", "boolean" given

Tags: php, symfony, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from Symfony application from 2.2 to 2.3 and I get this error on some pages. The problem seems to occur with forms.

I did what's writen here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.3.md

> Expected argument of type "string or
>   Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath", "boolean" given

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where does error occur? What code is near it?

Comment: Using *FOSUserBundle* or *FOSCommentBundle*? If so, see https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1424 and / or https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/issues/384

Comment: Nope. I'm not using FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Give us your code near line where error occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the form builder `'property_path' => false` should be replaced by `'mapped' => false`